# PHP shell_exec directory

Tags: php, exec, executable, shell-exec, subdirectory

I'm using shell_exec in PHP which works if I use the executable in the same folder, but doesn't work anymore if I point executable in subfolder.

I have this (which works):

```
shell_exec ("makescreen.exe /url=".$link."");
```

I would like to have this (doesn't work - it just skips the execution):

```
shell_exec ("/screens/makescreen.exe /url=".$link."");
```

Oh, and paths are in Windows mode.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be care of the difference of absolute path. relative path. execute path. For example, your dir structure is:

```
/home/my/php/script/test.php 
                   /makescreen.exe
```

and in you php script you call `shell_exec(makescreen.exe ***)`.

In this case, if you execute your script like `cd /home/my/php/script && php test.php`, then the execute path is `/home/my/php/script/` and the scirpt will find `makescreen.exe` in execute path, here is `/home/my/php/script/`

However, if you currently stay in `/home/my` and use this way `php /home/my/php/script/test.php` then the execute path is your current path, here is `/home/my`, and the script will find the `makescreen.exe` in `/home/my`, definitely failed.

If you use `/home/my/php/script/makescreen.exe` in your script, this is absolute path and wherever you are, it will find `makescreen.exe` in `/home/my/php/script/`

And if you want to put the executable file in subfolder. you can use relative path `subfolder/makescreen.exe` in your script and make sure the script can access it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

try using exec () with the complete path rather than relative path

```
 $oldcwd = getcwd();
 chdir($oldcwd+"/screens");
 exec("makescreen.exe /url=".$link."");
  chdir($oldcwd);
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same thing. This is 2 levels deep from server root already, and now I would like another subfolder - is this has to do anything with it? Should I be using absolute path from server root?